# Conversion of SEG-Y relative to MSL

Tags: geophysics, seismic

I am working on the conversion of CSF file from SonarWiz  into SEG-Y data. However, it comes back always related to the Sensor depth/altitude and never to the MSL.
I have tried changing the bytes from 61 to 69 to water depth info, I have tried editing the trace header and the EBCDIC Header.
But until now, I haven't managed to make it work.

Does anyone know how I fix this on the data?
I tried reading the SEG-Y definition document and there was something about location data stanza, but is this the only way ? And if it is, how do I create this?

PS: The data opens related to MSL in some softwares, but not in Seisee, which is where the client checks the data. Is there an explanation for this?

Thank you for any help!!